# Trigger - Error - AccountUpdateTerms: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101

Tags: trigger, unit-test, error-messages

I wrote a trigger that updates 4 fields into account that are related... our customization makes that we have Billing and Shipping accounts, so the shipping account has a lookup field that relates this shipping account to the billing account, so that this trigger does is basically change this 4 fields in all these relate accounts automatically.

In general, this trigger is working well, but I'm receiving the error when there are 30 - 40 accounts associated with this Billing account. How can I fix this issue?

```
trigger AccountUpdateTerms on Account (before update, after update) {

    Map<Id, Account> acc = new Map<Id, Account>();

    acc = trigger.oldMap;

    for(account newacc : trigger.new){

        if(newacc.Credit_Hold__c != acc.get(newacc.Id).Credit_Hold__c || newacc.Payment_Terms__c != acc.get(newacc.Id).Payment_Terms__c ||
           newacc.Price_Level__c != acc.get(newacc.Id).Price_Level__c){

           List<Account> accupd = new List<Account>();

           accupd = [SELECT Id,Company_Code__c,Bill_To_Account__c,Credit_Hold__c,Payment_Terms__c FROM Account WHERE Bill_To_Account__c =: newacc.Id ]; 

           if(trigger.isBefore && accupd.size() >0){

               for(account upd : accupd){

                   upd.ByPass_Validation_Rules__c= TRUE;

               }

               update accupd;

           }

           if(trigger.isAfter && accupd.size() >0){

               for(account upd : accupd){
                    upd.Company_Code__c = newacc.Company_Code__c;
                    upd.Credit_Hold__c = newacc.Credit_Hold__c;
                    upd.Payment_Terms__c = newacc.Payment_Terms__c;
                    upd.Price_Level__c= newacc.Price_Level__c;

               }

               update accupd;

           }

        }    

    }

}
```

Comment: Your immediate issue is the updates inside the for loop causing an infinite loop. If not for the SOQL limit you would hit either max stack depth or cpu timeout. Do the updates outside of the loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved my goal, made changes over my trigger which is now working as I expected.

```
trigger AccountUpdateTerms on Account (before update, after update){

    Map<Id, Account> acc = new Map<Id, Account>();

    acc = trigger.oldMap;

    List<Account> accupd = new List<Account>();

    accupd = [SELECT Id,Company_Code__c,Bill_To_Account__c,Credit_Hold__c,Payment_Terms__c FROM Account WHERE Bill_To_Account__c =: Trigger.newMap.keySet() ];


    for(account newacc : trigger.new){

        if(newacc.Credit_Hold__c != acc.get(newacc.Id).Credit_Hold__c || newacc.Payment_Terms__c != acc.get(newacc.Id).Payment_Terms__c ||
           newacc.Price_Level__c != acc.get(newacc.Id).Price_Level__c){


           ////////
           if(trigger.isBefore && accupd.size() >0){

               for(account upd : accupd){

                   upd.ByPass_Validation_Rules__c= TRUE;

               }

               update accupd;

           }

           ///////////
           if(trigger.isAfter && accupd.size() >0){

               for(account upd : accupd){
                    upd.Company_Code__c = newacc.Company_Code__c;
                    upd.Credit_Hold__c = newacc.Credit_Hold__c;
                    upd.Payment_Terms__c = newacc.Payment_Terms__c;
                    upd.Price_Level__c= newacc.Price_Level__c;

               }

               update accupd;

           }


        }    

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with the suggestion from Eric, I can also see you are updating account in afterUpdate of account trigger itself, which will also end up in recursion. Please use static variable of some class to avoid recursion in your trigger. Please go through the below link:

http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/avoid-recursive-trigger-salesforce/

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It will be great if you can create one handler class that handle trigger business logic(trigger framework), it will help you manipulate a lot of thing.BTW, this might solve the issue

- Please apply recursive handler
- I notice you have upd.ByPass_Validation_Rules__c= TRUE; which I
  assume you want to by pass validation rule.If yes, please you custom
  setting because use field to by pass validation rule won't work based
  on my experience.
- Instead of retrieve the Account in the loop, directly retrieve in Map
  .In the loop, you can just get the value.

  ```
  trigger AccountUpdateTerms on Account (before update, after update) { 
    Map<Id, Account> acc = new Map<Id, Account>();
              List<Account> accupd = new List<Account>();

              acc = trigger.oldMap;

              Map<Id,Account> mapAccountBillExist = [[SELECT Id,Company_Code__c,Bill_To_Account__c,Credit_Hold__c,Payment_Terms__c FROM Account WHERE Bill_To_Account__c IN : acc.keySet()]; 

          for(account newacc : trigger.new){

              if(newacc.Credit_Hold__c != acc.get(newacc.Id).Credit_Hold__c || newacc.Payment_Terms__c != acc.get(newacc.Id).Payment_Terms__c ||
                 newacc.Price_Level__c != acc.get(newacc.Id).Price_Level__c){

                   Account acct =mapAccountBillExist.get(newacc.Id);
                   acct.Company_Code__c = newacc.Company_Code__c;
                   acct.Credit_Hold__c = newacc.Credit_Hold__c;
                   acct.Payment_Terms__c = newacc.Payment_Terms__c;
                   acct.Price_Level__c= newacc.Price_Level__c;

                  accupd.add(acc);

              }    

          }

          if (accupd.size()>0){

            update accupd;
          }




      }
  ```